# How can I query kendo trees and MVVM models?

Tags: events, mvvm, telerik, kendo-treeview

According to the docs I should be able to do this ...

$("#tree").data("kendoTreeView").expand(".k-item");

Great if i want to expand everything, but what if i only want to expand nodes where the property "expanded" in my model items is set to true?

Is there a way i can query the tree based on something in the model then perform an action on all results?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The real answer here is quite long, the short version being as with everything kendo, spend hours with support to be given half the solution and told to write the rest yourself.

I got round this problem by using another library (jslinq) to query the model data.
This is yet another frustrating issue with kendo that really should at the very least be offered as a core part of the heirarchy data source at some basic level (essentially an incomplete implementation).